# PHP array values in a sequence

Tags: php, arrays, string

Hi i am retrieving values from my database to my web page.
here is my code

```
foreach ($rows as $r) { 
    echo $r->title;
}
```

Now I want all  my title values to be saved in a single variable separated by commas for example

```
$new_var = title_1,title_2,title_3;
```

how can i do that??

Comment: Do you want `$new_var` to be a `string` value or an `array` of values?

Answer (score 2):

```
$items = array();
foreach ($rows as $r)
        { 

$items[] = $r->title;

}

$new_var = implode(",", $items);
```

Using implode. This is quick and easy and handles the issue of a trailing comma that has to be fixed with other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use implode:

```
$new_var = array();
foreach ($rows as $r) { 
    echo $r->title;
    $new_var[] = $r->title;
}
$new_var = implode(',',$new_var);
```

Comment: *explain* are you sure ?

Comment: @Rikesh, sorry :) `implode`

Comment: Still it's incorrect. Find it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using append

```
 $s='', 
   foreach ($rows as $r)
            { 
     $s.=$r->title.',';// for title1,title2
    // $s.="'".$r->title."'".","; // if you want 'title1','title2'
    //or    use like $s.="'$r->title',"; 
     } 
     $s=  substr($s, 0,-1);//remove last comma
   echo $s;
```

Comment: what should i do if i want to add them like $s='title1','title2'

Comment: u want to add them like what ?

Comment: see again answer.use like $s.="'$r->title',";

Answer (score 1):

```
$titles =  array();    
foreach ($rows as $r)
{ 
    $titles[] = $r->title;
}    
$new_var = implode(',' , $titles);
```

http://php.net/function.implode

Answer (score 1):

If you taking the values from MySQL this may be helpful and an optimized way,

This is not an answer for your question just for an alternate option

**Note** The GROUP_CONCAT has the limitation please check it before querying more than 1028 characters.

Please refer this example

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

```
CREATE TABLE services (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
client_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
KEY (id));

INSERT INTO services
VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7);

SELECT id,client_id FROM services WHERE id = 3;

+----+-----------+
| id | client_id |
+----+-----------+
|  3 |         5 |
|  3 |         6 |
|  3 |         7 |
+----+-----------+

SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(client_id) FROM services WHERE id = 3 GROUP BY id;

+----+-------------------------+
| id | GROUP_CONCAT(client_id) |
+----+-------------------------+
|  3 | 5,6,7                   |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without obvious loop usnig [array_map](http://php.net/array_map).

```
$test_array = [(object) ['title' => 1], (object) ['title' => 2], (object) ['title' => 3]];

$result = implode(',', array_map(function($item)
            { return $item->title; }, $test_array));

var_dump($result); // string(5) "1,2,3"
```

[Demo.](http://3v4l.org/XH7K7)

Answer (score 0):

can use String joining with ", " and implode..

```
$a=array();
foreach ($rows as $r) {   
    $a[]="'".$r->title."'";
}
echo implode(",", $a);
```